# Выбор СУБД.

Tags: база-данных, nosql, sql

Какая на ваш взгляд СУБД наиболее удобная? Стоит ли придерживаться только SQL-решений ?  Почему вы выбираете именно такую систему управления базам данных, чем она особо отличается?

Comment: [эффектная](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Comment: @Asen - ты же сам писал о том, что noSQL это решето, так что, я не понимаю, к чему этот вопрос. В твоем случае - это **only sql**.

PS: Не ну, в этом сезоне, более эффектная, естественно, noSQL... SQL'ем уже никого не удивишь, уже не в моде :D

Comment: @karmadro4, описка....

Comment: Месячник холиворных тем на Хэшкоде?

 О себе: использую MSSQL, PostgreSQL и даже немного Mongo. Все нравятся, каждая по-своему, каждая на своем месте.

 Имею время от времени дело с MySQL, dBase, а когда то даже с PervasiveSQL. Эта троица нравится меньше )

Если придумаете конкретные вопросы по ним, поделюсь соображениями.

Comment: А чем MySQL уступает вышеперечисленному ряду?

Answer (score 2):

Выбор СУБД (по крайней мере у меня) зависит от задачи. Обычно выбор стоит между SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL и какой-нибудь embedded

Процентов на 90% выбор зависит от наличия оного на стороне сервера - клиент обычно сам ставит ограничение и говорит у меня Oracle и иное не моги. Если речь идет о БД которая должна крутиться на локалке - я обычно предпочитаю работать с MS SQL Server Express (привык уже как то) или Postgres. MySQL стараюсь обходить стороной (не всегда получается правда)

Касаемо embedded (то есть БД работающей в составе приложения) - предпочитаю Hypersonic SQL или SQLite.

Не SQL СУБД не использую - ИМХО технология или устарела (как с сетевыми и иерархическими) или еще не доросла до промышленного применения (как с объектными).

**Update**

В связи с неким флеймингом (отчасти наверное справедливым - ибо сам виноват). Проясню свою точку зрения. Дело в том, что я потребитель БД, никак не разработчик, не исследователь и проч. Как потребитель я ищу стандартное, устойчивое решение (то что называется industrial solution). Пока, увы NoSQL несмотря на оптимизм ряда товарищей не является таковым. Да, подвижки к этому есть. Тот же Oracle частично поддерживает объектную обработку и проч. Но в массе своей (не побоюсь 99%) - SQL рулит. Возможно придет день когда SQL будет списан в утиль - очень может быть, но пока это не так. А коли не так - то потребители юзают SQL, а там есть 2 кита: MS SQL Server и Oracle - так что хотим мы этого или не хотим все богатство выбора приходится делить между ними двумя с небольшими вариациями: MySQL, Postgres, embedded, pure Java и проч.

Comment: А чем вас так напугало использование MySQL. MSSQL и правда так хороша? 

----
Вряд ли NoSQL устарели...ведь они появились-то не так давно, позже SQL СУБД.

Comment: @Barmaley - memcache тоже? :) Это, как-бы, тоже noSQL.

А вот по поводу устарела, на мой взгляд, как раз таки наоборот - устарел SQL

Comment: Перечислите мне промышленные применения memcache - и сравните их с SQL'ом

Comment: @Asen - да нет я не боюсь его. Просто так исторически сложилось, что не люблю его и все тут. MSSQL не хорош и неплох - просто привык

Comment: @Barmaley, странно видеть такой вопрос от Вас... Как-бы у memcache и SQL "несколько" иные задачи, не?..

А истинную причину принципиального отказа **даже глянуть** в сторону noSQL, вы написали сами - **просто привык**. В этом нет ничего плохого, я лишь подчеркиваю те слова, которые вы написали, как-бы, про между-прочим.

Comment: @AlexWindHope я не говорил, что никогда не смотрел в сторону nosql. Я говорил про MySQL - прочтите внимательно. В сторону nosql смотрел, мне пока не понравилось. Как эксперименты - нормально, но как industry-ready решение нет. Для меня БД прежде всего способ хранения и доступа к данным и точка. У меня подход прагматичный: если задача/заказчик требует оного - значит будет. Пока не было ни одного заказчика который бы пришел и сказал - знаешь мне надо чтобы тут был nosql. Research мой направлен только в сторону мобильных приложений, но никак не в сторону nosql вы меня не путайте с субдешниками :

Comment: memcache - это не noSQL, это вообще не является базой данных. Вот memcachedb - да, это noSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Ну многое зависит от структуры проекта, нагрузок и некоторых других факторов. Как мне кажется однозначно ответить нельзя.

Answer (score -6):

Самая удобная субд - та, которую ты хорошо знаешь. А если начать использовать какую-то субд, просто потому что она якобы подходит для твоей задачи - ты только сделаешь хуже, т.к. улучшишь в одном месте, и сделаешь хуже в сотне других.

Comment: Не понял....

Comment: Если ты не знаешь тонкостей субд, которую хочешь использовать - только накосячишь.

Comment: Так, вроде, нет таких людей, которые садятся и сразу все знают, все тонкости...всему обучаются постепенно.

Comment: @razielsd, т.е. по-вашему получается, что раз я не знаю mongodb, я не должен делать проект более устойчивым и "скорострельным"? Как по-вашему я должен справиться с данной задачей в [данном вопросе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/114096/сильные-и-слабые-стороны-mongodb)?

Comment: @razielsd, если б все так рассуждали, писали бы мы до сих пор в машинных кодах. Для программиста очень важно постоянно расширять кругозор. Это касается и языков, и библиотек/фреймворков, и СУБД.

Comment: @Dex я бы тебе посоветовал в той задаче использовать MySQL с HandlerSocket :)

@Notafe Вы впадаете в крайности, я отвечал на вопрос "какая субд лучше", а не где и какую субд использовать. 

Для тех кто этого не понял, могу повторить: есть субд, которые лучше решают некоторую задачу, но нет универсальной лучшей субд. Если вы знаете слабые и сильные стороны используемой субд - тогда вы сможете ее эфективно использовать.

Хочу обратить ваше внимание еще раз: я не призываю не использовать новые решения, но их нужно использовать с осторожностью.

Comment: все не поместилось, продолжу :)
З.Ы. @Notafe специально для вас есть замечательная история: одна компания перешла с mysql на posgres, дескать он лучше, так они не осилили провести элементарных действий, которые позволили бы им эту скорость в их задачах получить, в результате все стало работать еще медленнее, чем до миграции. Вот потому я и говорю, что лучшая субд - которую ты знаешь.

Comment: @rezielsd, вы думаете, что две БД на одном сервере это хорошо?

Comment: [Для прочтения](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145061/)